# How to call intent flutter to open Phone info menu?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

`onTap` in flutter I want to call mobile `com.android.settings.RadioInfo`.

I am using [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) in flutter for that.

```
lteonly() async {
  final AndroidIntent intent =  AndroidIntent(
   action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
   data: 'com.android.settings.RadioInfo',
   componentName: null      
  );
  await intent.launch();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add intent method through kotlin or java in flutter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out :

```
 AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
 action: "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS",
 package: "your_app_package_name",
 data: "package:your_app_package_name",
  );
 intent.launch();
```